# There is a plugin or way to jump/go to definition/declaration in Sublime Text 3 like in Eclipse by Command+L-Click?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, robotframework

In Eclipse you can jump to definition/declaration by clicking on hyperlinks with pressing command key (control for Windows). I would like to use the same functionality for Sublime Text 3. Mostly I work with Robot Framework with a lot of files and would like to jump to the source of Keyword through whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sublime this kind of feature is provided by plugins.

Look at https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Robot%20Framework%20Assistant or https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Robot%20Framework, but be aware you can't use both, they conflict.

Comment: I tried them and I think that "go to" functionality doesn't work for .txt and .robot files.

Comment: Exactly. That's the language to write sublime plugins.

Comment: Exactly my major language C: Thank you.

Comment: just to be sure: did you try CTRL+P, then type @?

Comment: Yes, as I understand I have to type keyword after at sign but nothing happens.

Comment: Anyway I can use search through whole project.

Comment: It's odd but search in project can't find anything.

Comment: make sure you unchecked options in search dialog: case sensitive, regexp, whole word... and that you did not limit the file types to be explored to the wrong type

Answer (score 1):

This [plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Robot%20Framework%20Assistant) allows you to jump from .txt (.robot) files to the keyword's definition in .py and in .txt (.robot) in case they are resource files. Please read more here: https://github.com/andriyko/sublime-robot-framework-assistant

Comment: The Ctrl+Click works fine in Robot .txt files. But when I make a new file for some reason it does not work. Even if the file is a copy of the first one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can add below two plugins in pycharm, it will then allow you to navigate.

[image]